# Socket.IO and Node.js Core Cluster

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, express, socket.io

Is it possible to use Socket.IO with Node's core cluster (not the outdated module)?

I can fork multiple workers and it seems to work fine; however, when opening a connection I get the error: `solve: warn  - client not handshaken client should reconnect`

Here's the relevant code snippet (with a few simple things like expressjs config removed):

```
if ( cluster.isMaster ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++ ) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile( __dirname + '/public/html/index.html' );
    });

    io.configure( function() {
        var RedisStore = require('socket.io').RedisStore,
            opts = { host: 'localhost', port: 8888 };

        io.set('store', new RedisStore( { redisPub: opts, redisSub: opts, redisClient: opts } ));
    });

    app.listen( 8888 );

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit( 'some', 'data' );
    });
}
```

I've tried with and without using RedisStore and with the trick on this site (which I believe is obsolete now): http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

I've also looked at the code at http://www.ranu.com.ar/2011/11/redisstore-and-rooms-with-socketio.html, although I don't see how that code is any different than using MemoryStore.

All of my test connections are using Websockets (RFC 6455).  This works fine if I set numCPUs to equal 1.

Node.js version 0.6.17
Socket.io version 0.9.5
Expressjs version 2.5.9

Update - include console output (note, on this attempt the connection did ultimately work, although it threw the same errors):

```
info  - socket.io started
info  - socket.io started
info  - socket.io started
info  - socket.io started
info  - socket.io started
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 17644195072103946664
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/17644195072103946664
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 17644195072103946664
debug - websocket writing 7:::1+0
warn  - client not handshaken client should reconnect
info  - transport end (error)
debug - set close timeout for client 17644195072103946664
debug - cleared close timeout for client 17644195072103946664
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 17644195072103946664
debug - discarding transport
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 16098526291524652257
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/16098526291524652257
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 16098526291524652257
debug - websocket writing 7:::1+0
warn  - client not handshaken client should reconnect
info  - transport end (error)
debug - set close timeout for client 16098526291524652257
debug - cleared close timeout for client 16098526291524652257
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 16098526291524652257
debug - discarding transport
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 13419993801561067603
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/13419993801561067603
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 13419993801561067603
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
debug - websocket writing 5:::{"some":"data","args":[11354]}
debug - websocket writing 5:::{"some":"data","args":[36448]}
```

This is how the console output ends on a failure (fails about 9 times out of 10):

```
info  - transport end by forced client disconnection
debug - websocket writing 0::
info  - transport end (booted)
debug - set close timeout for client 1639301251431944437
debug - cleared close timeout for client 1639301251431944437
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 1639301251431944437
debug - discarding transport
debug - got disconnection packet
debug - got disconnection packet
```

Update - Added links to possible tickets on github:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/881

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/438

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but where is the io.listen(app) call?

Comment: I call it in my global vars: `io  = require('socket.io').listen(app)`

Comment: I'm surprised that your example works at all -- it seems that you point your `RedisStore` at `localhost:8888`, which is also where your web server is listening. You should point your `RedisStore` at your redis server (default port `6379`).

Comment: I believe socket.io creates the redis server itself, it's not something setup and already running on the machine.  You're probably right it should be a different port and I've since set it to 6379, although that hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: No, that's definitely not the case. You need to run a redis server yourself in order to use the RedisStore. It seems weird to me that socket.io doesn't give you an error about this.

Comment: When I point socket.io with RedisStore at a port where nothing's running, this is what I get: `Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED`. You probably have some other error in your code, or you're running other code than what is posted in your question.

Comment: Thought that was going to work.  I have redis up and running on my system at port 6379 (and changed my code to connect to that port) and the first connection worked fine, although opening a new browser tab and trying to connect then caused a handshake error.  Subsequent connections seem to have reverted to the same issue.

Comment: I also don't see any information being written to Redis.

Comment: are u tried the code without cluster (single node)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the issue may be related to the node module that Socket.IO comes installed with.

When I installed redis (`npm install hiredis redis`) and created the clients for the RedisStore using the redis module, everything suddenly worked perfectly.  I've been running for over an hour with ~500 concurrent connections and haven't seen a single error, and every node process is being utilized.

hiredis@0.1.14
redis@0.7.2

Running Redis 2.6rc3 on port 6379.

Update: In Node.s 0.8, it looks like the cluster library should be considerably more mature, so the above code/issues will probably become obsolete: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.7.8/api/cluster.html